# Fun with Java Properties Files

Tags: java, properties

I'm working on a class that requires the following logic:

```
If properties file @ "c:\somepath" (m_writePath) exists 
   if there is a value for the key offset 
      getProperty(offset)
   else
      write offset value
else 
   create property file ("c:/somepath")
   write offset value
```

Essentially this is my current setup:

```
public class myclass {

    /**
    * The properties file to store offset value.
    */
    private static Properties m_offsetProperty = new Properties();


    /**
    * Process stuff.
    */       
    private void processStuff() {
       File tmpFile = new File(m_writePath + "lastOffset.properties");

       if (tmpFile.exists()) {
          m_offsetProperty.load(new FileInputStream(m_writePath +    "lastOffset.properties"));
          m_offset = Long.getLong(m_offsetProperty.getProperty("offset"));     
       }
       else {
          createOffsetFile();
          m_offset = 0;
          setOffsetProperty();
       }
    }

    /**
    * Create properties file writePath/offset.properties.
    */
    private void createOffsetFile() {
       m_offsetProperty.setProperty("offset", String.valueOf(m_offset));
       File propFile = new File(m_writePath + "lastOffset.properties");
       FileWriter fw = null;
       fw = new FileWriter(propFile);
       m_offsetProperty.store(fw, null);
    }

    /**
    * Write offset to properties file writePath/offset.properties.
    */
    private void setOffsetProperty() {
       m_offsetProperty.setProperty("offset", String.valueOf(m_offset));
       m_offsetProperty.store(new FileOutputStream(m_writePath + "lastOffset.properties"), null);
    }
}
```

The properties file is being created and written to, but for some dang reason I cannot read the value of the offset key. Also the property file only contains that 1 key/value pair. I have taken out exception handling and many other methods for the sake of simplicity. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to close the file after writing.

Comment: If you can't close it because you need it for something else, you can always flush (for future reference).

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately m_offset = Long.getLong(m_offsetProperty.getProperty("offset")); is now giving me a null pointer and when I worked around it I still was not reading the offset value from the properties file. Any other ideas?

Comment: okay I changed Long.getLong(m_offsetProperty.getProperty("offset", "0")); to Long.valueOf(m_offsetProperty.getProperty("offset", "0"));

Comment: That, along with the suggestion above did the trick. Thanks.